# Gensim multicore LDA overflow error

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, multicore, gensim, lda

I'm having an issue running multicored LDA in gensim (generating 2000 topics, 1 pass using 15 workers). I get the error below, I initially thought it might not have to do with saving the model, but looking at the error (the code still keeps running, at least the process hasn't quit).
Anyone know what I can do to prevent this error from occurring?

````
python3 run.py --method MultiLDA --ldaparams 2000 1 --workers 15 --path $DATA/gender_spectrum/

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 241, in _feed
   obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
   cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
OverflowError: cannot serialize a bytes object larger than 4 GiB```
````